# 'str' object is not callable error is displayed on executing following code

Tags: python, function, multiple-inheritance

```
class Employee:
    def empname(self,empname):
        self.empname = empname

    def show(self,empname):
        print(self.empname)   
        
class EmployeeID(Employee):
    def showempid(self,empid):
       self.empid = empid


class EmployeeDOB(EmployeeID):
    def dob(self,dob):
        self.dob = dob
    def show(self):
        print('{}:{} {}'.format(self.empname,self.empid,self.dob))


    r2 = EmployeeDOB()
    r2.empname("Rakul")
    r2.showempid("1234")
    r2.dob("20/07/2001")
    r2.show()

    r2.empname("Rahul")
    r2.showempid("1234")
    r2.dob("20/07/2001")
    r2.show()
```

Comment: the main issue is you're overwriting your ```def empname()``` method with a string via ```self.empname = empname```.  Rename your ```def empname()``` to something else.

Comment: Also, for future posts, please consider posting the full traceback.

Comment: The same problem occurs in `EmployeeDOB`, where the `dob` method is being overwritten with `self.dob = dob`.  Again, choose two different names.